# Embedding usercontrols in an assembly

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Does anyone know a good way to embed user controls inside an assenbly so they can be reused across projects. I am not looking to create custom web controls. I have ascx files from different projects which I want to centrally use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=142
was the best one I found so far...

Answer (score 0):

See the question here: [Best way to share ASP.NET .ascx controls across different website applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28051/best-way-to-share-asp-net-ascx-controls-across-different-website-applications)

One person suggested following this tutorial: [Creating and Using User Control Libraries](http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/usercontrols/usercontrols.aspx)

Comment: I was looking something along the lines of http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASP2UserControlLibrary.aspx?msg=1782921

Comment: Any particular reason you'd like to load the controls that way?